# How to connect to the internet from Terminal when using a proxy with authentication

Tags: terminal, network, internet, proxy

I have to use proxy servers to connect to the internet. I have set all proxies in my system proxy settings. Now I can connect to Internet using my browser and applications.

But I cannot connect to internet from my terminal.

I tried

```
export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxyserver:port/"
```

But still terminal applications cannot connect to the internet.

Comment: Which command are you executing in Terminal to "connect to the internet"? Or how do you see that you are not able to connect?

Comment: The proxy server(with no s) you are talking of here is relaying your `web` connexions, not all your Internet connexions. `web` connexions are using ports 80, 443…. Internet connexions may use all the remaining ports of the 65536 set. As an example an `ssh` connexion will use port 22 which won't go through your `http` proxy server. Hence the question of patrix to help you get a better answer.

Comment: @patrix ping google.com

Comment: @TLE Ping is an exception to the rule and actually does not use the proxy at all, even if `http_proxy` is set. Ping expects a direct connection, and in a lot of cases when a proxy is being used, ping will fail although the proxy will still successfully connect.

Comment: try `curl -o /dev/null www.google.com` instead of `ping`

Comment: @patrix Nice tip, forgot about that.

Comment: @patrix my few commands are working, but git push not working. I mean few things are able to connect to internet, but not all.

Comment: @TLE As far as I remember git manages proxy itself, and doesn't use environment variables or the network settings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Terminal does not use proxy settings configured in the network preferences pane because it doesn't do any connection. Terminal just let you fire commands which will use the network in different ways.

When setting your `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables should not include the `http:` or `https:` prefixes.

Therefore the environment variable in your case should read:

```
http_proxy=username:password@proxyserver:port
```

Note: many old programs have issues with connecting through proxy servers which require authentication before connecting.

Additional Tip:

Due to our infrastructure we found it much easier to have users run [SquidMan](http://squidman.net/squidman/) locally and have it configured to connect to our main proxy. This allows the local machine to act as a proxy directly, and eliminates a lot of authentication issues etc when using proxy servers on Mac machines, especially in a mixed and AD environments.

In the case of using this method our `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` would be:

```
http_proxy=localhost:3128
```

Comment: you mean I have to write export http_proxy="username:password@proxyserver:port"

Comment: @TLE Correct. Terminal does not need to know the protocol since it already knows it's a HTTP connection.

Comment: But still I am unable to connect to the Internet.

Comment: @TLE Then the problem most likely with the authentication. Try setting the proxy without including the username and password, which means you will be prompted for the information when trying to connect. It normally indicates the proxy itself does not support the connection from Terminal. We had a similar problem internally which is why I suggested the SquidMan solution.

Comment: still not working??

Comment: @TLE Can you post the command your trying to run? Also did you close and re-open terminal after setting the environment variables?

Comment: exact command is export http_proxy="user:pass@ironport2.iitk.ac.in:3128"

Comment: I also entered this command in my .bashrc_profile file

Comment: @TLE I was referring to the command your trying to use that requires the proxy to be set. Also, take the user:pass part out completely and determine if it prompt you for your username and password.

Comment: I tried that also but mac didn't asked for username and password

Comment: @TLE Unfortunately that is the limit of my knowledge. As I mentioned in my answer, we ended up using SquidMan to solve the problem due to the authentication issues we were having.

Comment: I don't why ping is not working but I able to install ruby gems.

Comment: @TLE I answered this earlier: Ping is an exception to the rule and actually does not use the proxy at all, even if http_proxy is set. Ping expects a direct connection, and in a lot of cases when a proxy is being used, ping will fail although the proxy will still successfully connect.

Comment: → TLE: do you have a `Username:` and `Password:` defined within your `System Preferences > Network > Advanced… > Proxies > Web Proxy (HTTP)`?

Comment: "When setting your http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables should not include the http: or https: prefixes." - how standard is this behavior? I've found some programs don't care, and others do (I've had curl give SSL errors when the `https` prefix was included). I'm having trouble finding this discussed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue and in searching found [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99671/how-to-connect-to-the-internet-from-terminal-when-using-a-proxy-with-authenticat).  Adding some points that were successful for me (on a Mac, using Terminal):

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver:port
export HTTP_PROXY=${http_proxy}
```

And for https:

```
export https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyserver:port
export HTTPS_PROXY=${https_proxy}
```

From this I was able to use `git` and `brew` without any problems (and authenticating through a proxy).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following command in the Terminal Window.

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork $Interface $ssID $Password
```

Here,
`$Interface` is the "enX" style identifier for your AirPort card (usually en1, but it's en0 on MacBook Airs and en2 on Mac Pros, and can vary for other reasons as well)

`$ssID` is your network name, such as "Simon's SSID". Enclose it in quotes if it contains spaces.

`$Password` is your WEP, WPA-PSK, or WPA2-PSK password.

Comment: This configures the network, it does not allow the terminal itself to connect via a proxy.